# Tasks/Thread/Delegate.beginInvoke with Thread.Sleep()

Tags: c#, multithreading

In the example below only _DisplayUsingThreads(timesToDisplay) truly do operation in parallel. While the other two _DisplayUsingTasks and _DisplayUsingDelegates only do 4 at a time (on a quad core machine) and then wait for a second before doing 4 more. Why?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            delegate void DisplayDelegate();
            DisplayDelegate myDisplaySleep;

            private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
              const int timesToDisplay = 50;

                //_DisplayUsingDelegates(timesToDisplay);
                //_DisplayUsingTasks(timesToDisplay);
                //_DisplayUsingThreads(timesToDisplay);
            }

            private void _DisplayUsingTasks(int displayNumber)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < displayNumber; i++)
                {
                    Task task = new Task(DisplayIdSleep);
                    task.Start();
                }

            }

            private void _DisplayUsingThreads(int displayNumber)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < displayNumber; i++)
                {
                    Thread thread = new Thread(DisplayIdSleep);
                    thread.Start();
                }
            }
            private void _DisplayUsingDelegates(int displayNumber)
            {
                myDisplaySleep = DisplayIdSleep;

                for (int i = 0; i < displayNumber; i++)
                {
                    myDisplaySleep.BeginInvoke(null, null);
                }
            }

            private void DisplayIdSleep()
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Thread Id : {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a result of `Task` and `BeginInvoke` using thread pool threads, whereas creating your own thread, well, creates a thread.

Add `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(50, 0);` to `btnGo_Click` and observe what happens.

Comment: As Jason says, the underlying Windows Thread Pool deliberately limits the rate at which new threads can be created. It does this to mitigate the bad effects of starting many new threads simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The number of operations that can be queued to the thread pool is limited only by available memory; however, the thread pool limits the number of threads that can be active in the process simultaneously. Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the default size of the thread pool for a process depends on several factors, such as the size of the virtual address space.